# Getting an environment variable in a Java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, websocket, environment-variables, javac

I'm trying to open an http socket in an annotation processor on Windows, and am getting the following stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:397)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
...
```

I have looked into the error a little and it seems it may be because the annotation processor (run though javac) has no access to environment variables such as SystemRoot. I tested this by calling `System.getenv("SystemRoot")` from my annotation processor and it returned null. In normal code it returned `C:\Windows` as expected.

Is there any way to pass environment variables into javac? Or even set them programmatically although I suspect that's evil.

Comment: You can use the -D flag at the command line to override a System property. But I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for...

Comment: @durron597 It doesn't work with Javac unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java toolset is now contained in the runtime of Java. If you want to set Java variables using `-D`, all you have to do is call the tools from your own application. You can then pass `-Dmy.variable="hello world"` to `java` instead of `javac`.

Comment: Behind my PC at work now, will insert link once my Google connection is up at home. Looking for answer, resurecting the dead...